# How can I use Mathematica to sort the US Congressional Districts by Perimeter÷Area

Tags: curated-data, geography, entity

The United States is divided into 435 [congressional districts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_congressional_districts).  Some of their shapes can be really strange due to [gerrymandering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering).  I think that I can find very gerrymandered congressional districts if I sort them by the ratio of the perimeter/area.

The first step would be to import the perimeters and areas of all the congressional districts.  How can I obtain this data directly from *Mathematica*?

Comment: Try `Entity["USCongressionalDistrict", "Georgia:District9"]["Polygon"]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The US congressional districts are available as geographic entities in the form

```
Entity["USCongressionalDistrict", "Illinois:District7"]
```

As such, in principle you can enumerate them using

```
GeoEntities[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], "USCongressionalDistrict"]
```

but this is liable to timing out because you're asking for a lot of data, so instead you can break down the query into per-state lookups, giving you something like

```
Length[
 districts = Flatten[GeoEntities[#, "USCongressionalDistrict"] & /@ 
    GeoEntities[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], "USState"]]
 ]
(*449*)
```

(Or, as Michael pointed out, using the built-in `EntityList["USCongressionalDistrict"]` is way better.)

---

To get the data you want, you can use [`GeoArea`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoArea.html). To get the perimeter you can apply [`GeoDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoDistance.html) to the data but you need to fish it out first. You can get the shape of the district out using `EntityValue[#, "Polygon"]` and this will return things of the form

> Polygon[ GeoPosition[ {{lat1, lon1}, {lat2, lon2}, …, } ] ]

and you can't run `GeoDistance` on the `Polygon` - only on the `GeoPosition` object inside it or the lists of latitudes and longitudes inside that. Thus you can use

```
perimeter[polygon_] := GeoDistance[polygon[[1]]]
```

and to match it up you can define

```
area[district_] := EntityValue[district, "Area"]
```

To do the calculation, then, you can run

```
polygons = EntityValue[districts, "Polygon"]
```

which is relatively fast.

---

There is a slight complication with the data, though, and it's that not all districts appear as a single polygon. In fact, if you define `districts = EntityList["USCongressionalDistrict"]` and `polygons` as above, then there are

```
Select[polygons, Length[#] > 1 &] // Length
```

= 15 districts with multiple polygons. This is a bit surprising, since US congressional districts are meant to be territorially contiguous (and hence the gerrymandering stuff), but 11 of these have islands, which is fairly reasonable. Nevertheless, there are districts like the [Tennessee 2nd district](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/TN/2) which are not, in fact, contiguous, even though their exclaves are separated only by land. To visualize these 15 districts, use

```
multiPolygonDistricts = Pick[districts, Length[#] > 1 & /@ polygons]
GeoGraphics[EntityValue[#, "Polygon"], PlotLabel -> #, 
     ImageSize -> {{250}, {250}}] & /@ multiPolygonDistricts
```

---

In addition to this, there are some districts which don't have polygon data available, such as

```
EntityValue[Entity["USCongressionalDistrict","Pennsylvania:District19"],"Polygon"]
(*Missing["NotAvailable"]*)
```

There are 12 such districts and you can find them using

```
Pick[districts, MissingQ /@ polygons]
```

These turn out to be historical districts (like the aforementioned [PA 19th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennsylvania%27s_19th_congressional_district)) that are no longer in use, and as of November 2016 and MM v11 they are no longer present in the data.

---

There are also some irregularities in the formatting of the polygon data, so for example

```
EntityValue[Entity["USCongressionalDistrict", "Tennessee:District9"], "Polygon"]
```

has an output of the form `{Polygon[_]}`, but

```
EntityValue[Entity["USCongressionalDistrict", "Texas:District1"], "Polygon"]
```

has an output of the form `{{Polygon[_]}}` with a deeper list, whereas

```
EntityValue[Entity["USCongressionalDistrict", "Alaska:District0"], "Polygon"]
```

returns a straight `Polygon[_]`, though its insides are all messed up (i.e. it contains multiple polygons inside it, instead of a list of polygons, which will definitely mess with the `perimeter` calculator above); either way, if you're studying gerrymandering you presumably want to leave out this district as it's the entirety of Alaska. Again, this is buggy data which I'll leave to you to report.

EDIT: some issues with the data seem to have been resolved, but it's not necessarily all good yet. It's also not clear to me whether the fix is version-dependent (or fixed upstream at the server), either. So: watch out for this if you want to implement this.

---

To get clean data, then, you can do

```
cleanPolygons = Flatten /@ DeleteCases[DeleteMissing[polygons], Polygon[_]];
cleanDistricts = DeleteCases[Pick[districts, Not@*MissingQ /@ polygons], 
                   Entity["USCongressionalDistrict", "Alaska:District0"]];
```

You can now calculate the perimeters using

```
perimeters = Total /@ Map[perimeter, cleanPolygons, {2}]
```

which is now quite fast as well (the previous implementation was slowing the whole thing down). Calculating the areas as

```
areas = EntityValue[cleanDistricts, "Area"]
```

you finally have enough to get your rankings: doing

```
TableForm[
 (data = SortBy[{EntityValue[cleanDistricts, "Name"], perimeters^2/areas
           }\[Transpose], Minus@*Last])[[1 ;; 5]]
 ]
```

gets you for the top five

```
District                                        p^2/A
"North Carolina 12th Congressional District"    365.611
"Florida 5th Congressional District"            244.518
"North Carolina 1st Congressional District"     234.952
"North Carolina 4th Congressional District"     228.47
"Maryland 3rd Congressional District"           226.788
```

And, indeed, you get some pretty heavy gerrymandering going on:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As an interesting trivia, note that the fourth place on this list, Maryland's 3rd district, really stretches the definition for "contiguous" - if you [zoom in on the map](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/MD/3) into the Baltimore harbour, there's not a lot of district land connecting Federal Hill and Little Italy.

It's also important to note that it matters what year the data is from: Mathematica seems to be using the 2014 electoral districts, which have since changed in some states (North Carolina in particular, but also Florida and Virginia) precisely because they were deemed to be too gerrymandered. For a good illustration of the changes see [this NPR animation for the NC redistricting](http://www.npr.org/2016/03/10/469548881/north-carolinas-congressional-primaries-are-a-mess-because-of-these-maps).

Comment: See @Michael E2 answer for the suggestion of using perimeter^2 / area (so that the answer is dependent only on the shape and not the size)

Comment: @mikado That's a different quantity that will yield a different ranking, and it's for the OP to decide. Having a dimensional answer is not particularly problematic, as the ranking will be the same regardless of the unit system in use.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The ranking could be different as they are different calculations, but I agree about leaving it up to the OP to ask. Just a side note, you shouldn't have to write `Apply[x] /@ list` when `x@@@list` does the same thing.

Comment: It *does* take a long time... do you know what that is?  It seems like it shouldn't take so long.

Comment: @JasonB No, the ranking will be the same regardless of the unit system: 4km is bigger than 2km, and that's still true if you convert them to miles before comparing. And yeah, `@@@` works equally well there; for this instance I found that syntax clearer. To each their own.

Comment: I think @MichaelE2 's suggestion is not concerning unit system, but rather since area scales like $[\text{length}]^2$ and perimeter like $[\text{length}]^1$, my original ratio perimeter/area will simply yield smaller numbers for large districts with exactly the same shape as small districts.  This may cause me to inadvertently miss heavily gerrymandered big districts.  The dimensionless ratio perimeter^2/area is *definitely* better in that regard.

Comment: @QuantumDot See expanded answer.

Comment: One might argue that hexagonal honeycomb districts would be most optimal with lowest `p^2/A` value of `8 Sqrt[3]`, or about `13.9`. Of course this ignores the fact that it would be most fair to have equal-population districts and population density is uneven (and minor point that Earth really has a curved surface, effect which mostly vanishes with small districts), but I believe this is still a reasonable yardstick to compare with numbers hovering in hundreds...

Comment: Too bad I can't give another +1 for the NPR link…

Comment: @J.M. I know, I'm really happy I found it. Really shows how crazy it gets.

Answer (score 7):

First (*update:* I guess the missing ones should be deleted),

```
alldistricts = DeleteMissing@ EntityList["USCongressionalDistrict"];
allpolygons = #["Polygon"] & /@ alldistricts (* // DeleteMissing *);
```

Then find the `GeoArea[poly]` and perimeter* of them.  Note that you might want to compute a dimensionless quantity such as perimeter^2/area.

*Update:*
The perimeter was a little tricker than my original blithe remark led one to believe.  Here is an improvement over `GeoDistance`, at least in terms of reliability:

```
perimeters = Total[allpolygons /. Polygon :> GeoLength@*GeoPath, {2}]
areas = Total[GeoArea /@ allpolygons, {2}]  (* why not put in the areas, too *)
```

Comment: I'm not sure `GeoDistance` works here - trying `GeoDistance[Entity[ "USCongressionalDistrict", "Alabama:District1"][ "Polygon"]]` returns zero.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty `GeoDistance[]` works on the points of the polygon, though.  I guess I should clarify.

Comment: I agree. As is, `GeoDistance[poly]` produces either zeroes or an error. Do run it through to the end for the full list - the data is much less homogeneous than you'd assume at first brush.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Surely the OP can deal with the problematic data.  SE isn't a consulting service, and I don't get paid for participating. :)

Comment: That's up to you. But as is, your answer doesn't get the OP anywhere closer to their stated goal. *None* of the polygons from your method yield useful answers with your code.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty How do you mean?  I get numbers that seem reasonable for all but the missing ones and "Alaska at-large rep", which consists of 81 polygons, but I don't know why `GeoDistance` balks on it.

Comment: Apologies - it simply wasn't clear what your code means. You seem to be implying that `GeoDistance /@ allpolygons` will be sufficient, and that is zeroes and errors only (and, come to think of it, those zeroes are really strange). Data irregularities aside, `Apply[GeoDistance, allpolygons, {2}]` does seem to work, but your answer does need to state that this is the required manipulation; I find it misleading as is.

Comment: In particular, `result = EntityValue[
  Entity["USCongressionalDistrict", "Alabama:District1"], "Polygon"]` and then `GeoDistance[result]` is bizarre.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm working on an update. Thanks for the help. :)  -- I found something more reliable than `GeoDistance`.  Since the OP is an experienced *M* user and only asked, as I read it, how to get started, that was my intention.  But how to use `GeoDistance` was stated in a way that reflected how I was actually doing.